# How to transform JavaScript OOP into functional

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, functional-programming

I'm curious how my game would look like in functional style instead of OOP.

Here are core lines of code in Node.js:

```
if (!player.owns(flag) && player.near(flag)  && flag.isUnlocked()) {
    player.capture(flag);
}
```

My guess was, it could look like this:

```
var canCapture = [not(owns), isNear, canUnlock].every(function(cond) {
    return cond(playerData, flagData);  
});

if(canCapture) {
    // how to capture?
}
```

But not sure, as not experienced functional coder. I'm interested in every answer close to the subject (it can be even in other programming style).

Comment: I'm not sure where the OOP part is in your code? Or even what you understand under this term.

Comment: You have the Player class instance with methods: "owns", "near", "capture". You also have Flag class instance with methods "isUnlocked".

Comment: But those objects would still stay. So they won't be converted from OOP to functional... Is you'r question actually: **How can I write an `All` predicate where I could provide an array of functions/values and it should return `true` when all are `true`?**

Comment: Yes, objects will stay but rather as a general data containers ({lat:33.33, lon:33.33, name:"Rob"}) than dedicated class instances. Does functional style refuse using objects? I'm just curious how to code such a game's rule "if player is without flag and flag is laying unlocked near to him, then he automatically captures this flag." in functional programming. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look somewhat like this:

```
if (!player.owns(flag) && player.near(flag)  && flag.isUnlocked()) {
    capturingPlayer = player.capture(flag);
}
```

where `capturingPlayer` is a *new* object, whose difference to `player` is that is has captured a flag. `player` is unmodified by the call to `capture`.

If you prefer a "non-OO" syntax (whatever that could mean)

```
if (!owns(player, flag) && near(player, flag)  && isUnlocked(flag)) {
    capturingPlayer = capture(player, flag);
}
```

---

To expand and hopefully clarify a bit:

Functional programming, in the sense employed by the functional programming community, does *not* just mean "functions/procedures are first-class objects".

What it *does* mean is that functions are functions in the *mathematical* sense, i.e.

- All functions return a value.
- Every function returns the same value every time it's passed the same arguments.
- A function has no side-effects whatsoever - there are no mutable objects or assignment.

So, as long as none of your object's methods mutate the object, you don't really need to change much to program in a "functional style".

---

Edit:

Unfortunately both "functional" and "object-oriented" (in particular) are pretty ill-defined concepts.
Try and find a definition of "object-oriented" - there are at least as many definitions as there are people attempting to define it.
To get an understanding of functional programming, read [*Why functional programming matters*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) by John Hughes, at least twice.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification! So does it mean, that functional programming is often OO-programming restricted to immutable objects (in general)? Could it be: `if (!player.owns(flag) && player.near(flag)  && flag.isUnlocked()) { player = player.capture(flag); }`

Comment: @Kasztan: No, it doesn't. What I meant was that syntax isn't essential, and that it's *possible* to write in a "functional style" using dot-notation and immutable "objects". It's not very common, though.